# Scalar multiplication dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
data = {'x': [1, 2, 3]}
```

I would like to multiply the list of the key 'x' by a scalar for example:

```
data['x']*2
```

but I obtain:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

insted of:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't multiply the list by two, multiply each element by two and reassign to the key `'x'`.

```
>>> data = {'x': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> data['x'] = [2*x for x in data['x']]
>>> data
{'x': [2, 4, 6]}
```

(The reassignment is optional depending on what you try to do)

Comment: I found this other workaround with numpy: `data['x'] = np.array(data['x'])**2`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over its elements:

```
  map(lambda x: x * 2, data['x'])
```